# How do you make a nested column chart with ggplot2 in R/RMarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

How do you use ggplot2 in R/RMarkdown to make a column chart where the independent variable is the y-axis and two ordinal dependent variables are on the x-axis, where one of those ordinal variables is nested within the other? For example: life-expectancy on the y-axis, year-of-birth on the x-axis, and continent of birth nested within each year-of-birth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to give a small example. This will help to plot multiple categorical data for a column plot / bar plot.

```
    MoT <- c(rep("Train",3),rep("Aeroplane",5))
    Casulty <- c("survived","not survived","not survived","survived","survived","survived",
"survived","not survived")

    df <- data.frame(MoT,Casulty)

    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(df, aes(MoT)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Casulty), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: when i try to use ggplot in Rmarkdown, i get an error that the package is not available?

Comment: is it working in R console? Also which version of R you are using? ggplot2 is compabtible with R>=3.1.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html

Comment: @RajatMishra Couple of comments. Use of `library()` is better alternative to `require()`. `..count..` is not mandatory to mention in `aes` as `stat_bin` will provide it when called from `geom_bar`.

Comment: @MKR agree with your comments.